# Asp.net MVC Form posting

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms, post

I have form like this in my Contact_Us view

```
@model vidiaweb_com.Models.Contact_US
....
<div id="contactus">
   <div class="container">
    <form class="form-group col-md-8">
        <div id="contactuspost">
            <h3 class="txtformat">Contact Us</h3>
            <p class="txtformat">
                We are here to answer any questions you may have. Reach out to us and we will respond as soon as we can.
            </p>
            <p class="txtformat">
                Even if there is something you have always wanted to experience and can't find it on combadi, let us know and we promise we'll do our best to find it for you and send you there.
            </p>
            <br />
            <div class="form">
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Contact_Us"))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 txtformat" })
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>                            
                        ....
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
   </div>
</div>
....
@Html.Partial("_MainFooter")
```

and this is my Contact_UsController

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Email,Phone,Message,Date")] Contact_US contact_US)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Contact_US.Add(contact_US);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

but in view when I Fill the Form and  then click on submit button , it doesn't call `Create` action in the `Contact_Us` Controller. something like this is in my url

`http://localhost:50074/Contact_Us/Index?__RequestVerificationToken=nrlDXOQglmGEzSQMqOqxm8ol4GiKeLffHoQUnLmuwhlIGcSFQfBrQxhZA8EL39nPLmG1FJQK42X284v60l6oepOytsmHLgwDOJYOgfmYnFU1&Name=dg&Email=d%40d.com&Phone=SF&Date=&Message=SFD`

and it redirect again into my Contact_Us index view.

I had another form in my project like this but that one works correctly. does anyone have any idea what would the problem may be? thanks

Comment: Is that the only form in your view? (it looks like you might have nested forms which is invalid). And is it the `Index()` method that generated this view.

Comment: yes @StephenMuecke I have just this one form in my view. thanks for your care

Comment: Are you sure? Can you post the whole view.

Comment: yes please wait a minute to edit @StephenMuecke

Comment: You do have nested forms :) - remove the outer `<form class="form-group col-md-8">`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123049/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-neda-derakhshesh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have nested forms (the `<form class="form-group col-md-8">` contains your `@Html.BeginForm()`) which is invalid html and not supported.

The url your seeing is because your browsers submits the outer most form. Since the default method for a form is a GET, and the default action is to submit to the method that generated it (in your case `Index()`) it is generating a query string value for each form control.

Remove the `<form class="form-group col-md-8">` tag and its closing `</form>` tag and the form generated by `Html.BeginForm()` will be submitted to the `Create()` POST method.